# flatMap upper boundary for number cached items

Tags: rx-java2

I am studying RxJava2 performance. I thought that bufferSize is upper restriction for number of cached items when upstream produce items faster than observer can process it. But it looks that it is only optimalization for initialization of queue.

Buffer size of operators (Observable) is unbounded?

This is my example:

```
private static void overflow(){

        Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .doOnNext(onNext ->{
            LogHelper.print("subject: onNext: " + onNext);
        })
        .flatMap(item ->{
            return getObservable()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
        }, false, 2, 2)
        .subscribe(onNext ->{
            LogHelper.print("onNext: " + onNext);
        }, onError ->{
            LogHelper.print("onError: " + onError);
        });

        // TimeUnit is second.
        ThreadHelper.sleep(500);
    }

    private static Observable<Object> getObservable(){
        return Observable.defer(() -> {
            // TimeUnit is second.
            ThreadHelper.sleep(10);

            return Observable.just(new Object());
        });

    }
```

But exception is never thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Observable` in v2 doesn't support backpressure and thus `flatMap` can't bound its buffers. The `bufferSize` is a hint about how much items to anticipate in a bursty flow. Otherwise, most `Observable`s will buffer everything.